# How to integrate plugins in PhoneGap Build

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I tried adding the following in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.zendrive.phonegap.sdk" version="1.2.0" /> 
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" />
```

This is not working. 
I also tried installing plugin in app before uploading zip file on build.phonegap.com but that also didn't work. So, how can I actually install plugins in the app if you are using build.phonegap.com cloud build service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the official documentation and still can't use the plugins, contact PhoneGap Build support.

[Zendrive plugin documentation at PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1372)
[Zendrive plugin at GitHub](https://github.com/zendrive/zendrive-sdk-phonegap-plugin/blob/a498fe1/README.md)

[Toast plugin documentation at PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1182)
[Toast plugin at GitHub](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/2fdfde7/README.md)

[PhoneGap Build community support](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)

Comment: Thanks, actually nowhere in the documentation was it mentioned what folder structure should be there for "phonegap build" projects. I was using the folder structure of my old cordova project and the problem is that "phonegap build" required index.html and config.xml in the same folder as opposed to cordova project where config.xml remains outside of www folder.